# How to redirect page into iframe using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

On my website I have a jQuery script which fades in the body of page, and then when a user clicks on a relative link the body fades out and redirects the user to the new page and the script then starts again.

My colleague advised me it would be better to have the main content put into an iframe in order to stop having the whole body refreshing when changing pages, but the problem is that when a user clicks on a relative link the iframe fades out but instead of the new page targeting the iframe it just opens up the page.

How do I fix this? I think the error occurs after the line `$("body").fadeIn(2000);`.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").css("display", "none");
        $("body").fadeIn(2000);
        $(".transition").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href;
            $("iframe").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
        });

        function redirectPage() {
            window.location = linkLocation;
        }
    });
    </script>

    <a href="competition.html" class="transition" target="iframe">Home</a>

    <iframe src="main.html" name="iframe" seamless="seamless" width="800" height="800">
    </iframe>
```

Comment: why not to use separete divs (sections) for this? put everything you need in one page and show/hide it on demand

Comment: I just tried , Your code works fine , onclicking the relative link i am getting a new page in the iframe.

Comment: The content that opens up in the iframe contain no links, only text. All relative links are on the parent page. If you did what I did and it worked, I'll have to go back and try again lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't change location of iframe window because many times it's not allowed. Due to security reasons
some websites set X-Frame-Options to SAMEORIGIN you can test this, just change

```
//your syntax is wrong here see below for correct
```

`window.location = linkLocation`

to

```
//correct way to change the location of iframe window
```

`window.frames['yourframeName'].location=linkLocation`

and `<a>`'s link `href` to `http://www.google.com`

now see the error in the console.

hence your syntax is wrong you are not changing the location of your iframe you are changing loacation of your main page (window) which contains the targeted iframe. So the correction to get your work done is

```
function redirectPage() {
        $('iframe').attr('src',linkLocation);
        $('iframe').fadeIn()
    }
```

Comment: Right, your suggestion worked... sort of. I can now get the source of the iframe to change to the new page - but now when I click on another relative link the source of the iframe stays the same.

EDIT - I found out the reason. I was clicking the link to the page which holds the iframe, so the script was stuck. I changed the href to google for testing purposes and the script works fine! I'll verify your answer on my actual site before accepting your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("iframe").src` to change the src attribute of the iframe, and setting it to the clicked link href.

Also you should get the href by using `$(this).attr("href");`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").css("display", "none");
        $("body").fadeIn(2000);
        $(".transition").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = $(this).attr("href");
            $("iframe").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage(linkLocation));
        });

        function redirectPage(url) {
            document.getElementById("iframe").src = url;
        }
    });
    </script>

    <a href="competition.html" class="transition" target="iframe">Home</a>

    <iframe src="main.html" id="iframe" name="iframe" seamless="seamless" width="800" height="800">
    </iframe>
```